# problem with pyopengl in linux

Tags: python, pyopengl

I am a beginner.
I want to use pyopengl in linux but I have a problem.
I try to import pyopengl module as below :

```
from OpenGl.GL import *
```

but interpreter shows this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named OpenGl.Gl
```

what should I do?

Comment: This is a rule about abbreviations: using capital characters. G means *Graphical*, L means *Library*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is a [case-sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive) language. Both `G` and `L` should be uppercase letters:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
```